# Deep maybe stack with yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to set an authorization scheme where I check that 1. user is logged in 2. user has access to a certain object. For this I first call `maybeAuthId`, then try to get the current object, and 'join' to another table which lists permissions. There are two levels of maybe-cases and one level of empty-list case. I thought of using MaybeT, but either I'm too tired to get it to work or the "not really monad transformer"-handler-transformers can't be used with MaybeT. Is there a nice way to handle deep maybes?

Edit:

I was a bit unclear it seems. I meant that I have something like this:

```
case foo of
   Nothing -> something
   Just foo' -> do
      bar <- somethingelse
      case bar of
         Nothing -> ...
         Just bar' -> ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can totally use `MaybeT` for Yesod. Just do it like this:

```
runMaybeT $ do
  uid <- MaybeT maybeAuthID
  car <- MaybeT . runDB . getBy $ UniqueCarOwner uid
  location <- MaybeT . liftIO . ciaLocateLicensePlate . licensePlate $ car
  country <- MaybeT . findCountry $ location
  return (car, country)
```

As you said, most functions aren't optimized for generic error handling in Yesod. However, if you have something of the form `Monad m => m (Maybe a)`, you can simply use `MaybeT` to turn it inside out into `Monad m => Maybe (m a)`.

Comment: Thanks. Been a while since I used transformers, and forgot I need to wrap them in MaybeT.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, your layers look like:

```
Maybe [Maybe r]
```

... and you want to `join` the two `Maybe`s together, but the list is in the way.  This is precisely the problem `sequence` solves:

```
sequence :: (Monad m) => [m r] -> m [r]
```

Note that if we specialize `sequence` to the `Maybe` monad we get:

```
sequence :: [Maybe r] -> Maybe [r]
```

In this particular case, `sequence` will return a `Nothing` if there is at least one `Nothing` in the list, but if they are all `Just`s, then it will join them all into a single `Just`.

All that remains is to map `sequence` over the outer `Maybe`:

```
fmap sequence :: Maybe [Maybe r] -> Maybe (Maybe [r])
```

Now this is exactly in the form we need for join:

```
join . fmap sequence :: Maybe [Maybe r] -> Maybe [r]
```

So, intuitively, what the above function does is that if all the inner `Maybe`s are `Just`s and the outer `Maybe` is a `Just`, then it fuses the entire result into a single `Just` containing the list.  However, if any `Maybe` (either the inner ones or outer one) is a `Nothing`, the final result is a `Nothing`.

Notice that despite doing a bunch of blind type-chasing, we ended up with a function that intuitively does the right thing.  This is the power of abstractions grounded in category theory.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you mean by "handle deep maybes", but you can use monadic `join` (from `Control.Monad`) to remove one level of nesting at a time.

```
ghci> :m +Control.Monad
ghci> join (Just (Just 3))
Just 3
ghci> join (Just Nothing)
Nothing
ghci> join Nothing
Nothing
```

Using MaybeT is probably a better fit for your problem, though. If you clarify what you're trying to do, we could help you formulate it with MaybeT.