# refactor maybe stack in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

Using Yesod, I want to show the user's profile name in the navigation bar of every page and want to link, with the `ProfileId`, to the profile-page of a user. `config/models` contains:

```
User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe
    UniqueUser ident
Profile
    username Text
    user UserId
    UniqueProfile user
    UniqueUsername username
```

Snippet from `Foundation.hs`:

```
defaultLayout widget = do
    master <- getYesod
    mmsg <- getMessage
    maid <- maybeAuthId
```

With the user-id I can query for the profile, but it's burried in `Maybe`s.
[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130732/deep-maybe-stack-with-yesod) gives a good hint how to handle all those `Maybe`s... but, with my little experience of Haskell, I'm still struggling with it.

I came up with:

```
mpid <- runMaybeT $ do
    ouid <- MaybeT maybeAuthId
    (Entity pid _) <- MaybeT . runDB . getBy $ UniqueProfile ouid
    return pid

mprofilename <- runMaybeT $ do
    ouid <- MaybeT maybeAuthId
    (Entity _ p) <- MaybeT . runDB . getBy $ UniqueProfile ouid
    return $ profileUsername p
```

This works, but is not optimal - repeating code and double database hits. How can I refactor this code?

I thought this would work:

```
(mpid, mprofilename) <- runMaybeT $ do
    ouid <- MaybeT maybeAuthId
    (Entity pid p) <- MaybeT . runDB . getBy $ UniqueProfile ouid
    return (pid, profileUsername p)
```

but, alas, a no-go:

```
Foundation.hs:91:9:
    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe (t0, Text)'
                with actual type `(t1, t2)'
    In the pattern: (mpid, mprofilename)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (mpid, mprofilename) <- runMaybeT
            $ do { ouid <- MaybeT maybeAuthId;
                (Entity pid p) <- MaybeT . runDB . getBy $ UniqueProfile ouid;
                return (pid, profileUsername p) }
    In the expression:
        do { master <- getYesod;
             mmsg <- getMessage;
             maid <- maybeAuthId;
             (mpid, mprofilename) <- runMaybeT
                 $ do { ouid <- MaybeT maybeAuthId;
                 (Entity pid p) <- MaybeT . runDB . getBy
                     $ UniqueProfile ouid;
                                          .... };
           .... }
```

I understand the error, but I don't get it solved.

Enlighten me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to bind the result as if it is a `(Maybe a, Maybe b)`, but it is actually a `Maybe (a, b)`.

You could convert it easily enough:

```
unpairMaybe :: Maybe (a, b) -> (Maybe a, Maybe b)
unpairMaybe (Just (x, y)) = (Just x,  Just y)
unpairMaybe Nothing       = (Nothing, Nothing)
```

Then this should work:

```
(mpid, mprofilename) <- liftM unpairMaybe $ runMaybeT $ do
                ouid <- MaybeT maybeAuthId
                (Entity pid p) <- MaybeT . runDB . getBy $ UniqueProfile ouid
                return (pid, profileUsername p)
```

Comment: That worked, though, I needed to change it a little: 
    `unpairMaybe Just (x, y) = (Just x,  Just y)` 
need extra parenthesis: 
    `unpairMaybe (Just(x,y))    = (Just x, Just y)`.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been typing too quickly. I've fixed that line now.